# What books have helped you get a grasp of n-Tier development

Tags: c#, design-patterns, n-tier-architecture

What books have helped you get a grasp of n-Tier development (Presentation Layer, UI Business Objects, Data Business Objects, and Data sets)?

I'd prefer books, but blogs and other sites are welcome suggestions too.  I've inherited a n-Tier designed application at a new job and although it's taken me some time to get used to it, I see the usefulness of the concepts.  Moving forward, I want to make sure my development falls in the same standards.  A focus in C# would be great too.

Also, are there other design patterns that you would suggest for scalability?  Is there any suggested reading you can provide for those design patterns?

Answer (score 9):

Reading [Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture](http://martinfowler.com/books.html#eaa) (PoEAA) was a great eye-opener for me.  It's geared towards the web, and goes into great detail in explaining how all those tiers ought to interact.

IIRC, examples are in both C# and Java.

Comment: Wonderful book. Haven't read it thoroughly, but it makes some very good points, and is generally well written. +1

Answer (score 6):

This is the standard list of books I hound people in my office to read, and the order in which I would read them:

*Agile Principles, Patterns, and Practices in C#* - Robert C. Martin, Micah Martin
*Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code* – Martin Fowler
*Working Effectively With Legacy Code* – Michael Feathers
*Domain Driven Design: Tackling Complexity in the Heart of Software* – Eric Evans
*Applying Domain Driven Design and Patterns: With Examples in C#* - Jimmy Nilsson

If you only want to read one book, read the Robert C. Martin book.  It will make you want to read others.  The Refactoring book is mostly a catalog of techniques, more of a reference book than an instruction manual, but still very well worth having.  If you're doing all greenfield development right now, save the Legacy Code book for last.

Answer (score 2):

Doing Objects in Visual Basic 2005 [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321320492) is the best for beginners

OOP: Building Reusable Components with Microsoft Visual Basic .NET  [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735613796)
 is also a good book

Answer (score 1):

[Expert C# 2005 Business Objects, Second Edition](http://www.apress.com/book/view/1590596323)

It's purpose isn't to teach about n-Tier, but building the framework proposed in the book helps a lot in understanding how things work in a n-Tier world.

Answer (score 0):

books are great for specifics and details of certain solutions/approaches, but the [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) principle is sufficient to logically derive the n-tier architecture